# Row to Column in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of data in this format:-

[image]

Note: It starts from Jan-17 to Dec-17. However, for this exercise I limit it to 3 months (Jan to Mar).

I wish to convert the data into this format:-

[image]

How can i achieve it using Excel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a one-off or a recurring task?

Comment: This is pretty trivial using Power Query (Get & Transform Data). Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: It is one-off task. I'm using Excel 2016.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like below, using a double For Loop to loop through rows and then columns and transfer data to Sheet2 in the desired format (this won't add the headers to Sheet2, but it will give you a some guidance as to how to go about it):

```
Sub Summarize()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Sheet with data
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2") 'Summarised Sheet
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A
LastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 2 To LastRow 'loop through rows
    For col = 6 To 14 Step 4 'loop through columns
    'replace 14 with (LastCol - 4) if you wish to do all the months instead of just the first 3
        FreeRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'get the next free row to transfer data to
        ws.Range("A" & i & ":D" & i).Copy ws2.Range("A" & FreeRow) 'copy the first 4 columns into the free row
        ws2.Cells(FreeRow, 5).Value = "20" & Mid(ws.Cells(1, col).Value, 5, 2) 'get the year from the header
        ws2.Cells(FreeRow, 6).Value = Left(ws.Cells(1, col).Value, 3) ' get the month name from header
        ws2.Cells(FreeRow, 7).Value = ws.Cells(i, col).Value 'transfer values
        ws2.Cells(FreeRow, 8).Value = ws.Cells(i, col + 1).Value
        ws2.Cells(FreeRow, 9).Value = ws.Cells(i, col + 2).Value
        ws2.Cells(FreeRow, 10).Value = ws.Cells(i, col + 3).Value
    Next col
Next i
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

I've added a couple of lines to the code to attempt to optimize the speed of it, also removed the Copy & Paste and altered it to pass the values without copying anything, please have a look below:

```
Sub Summarize()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Sheet with data
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2") 'Summarised Sheet
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A
LastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'optimize code:
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

For i = 2 To LastRow 'loop through rows
    For col = 6 To 14 Step 4 'loop through columns
    'replace 14 with (LastCol - 4) if you wish to do all the months instead of just the first 3
        FreeRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'get the next free row to transfer data to
        ws2.Cells(FreeRow, 1).Value = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        ws2.Cells(FreeRow, 2).Value = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
        ws2.Cells(FreeRow, 3).Value = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
        ws2.Cells(FreeRow, 4).Value = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
        ws2.Cells(FreeRow, 5).Value = "20" & Mid(ws.Cells(1, col).Value, 5, 2) 'get the year from the header
        ws2.Cells(FreeRow, 6).Value = Left(ws.Cells(1, col).Value, 3) ' get the month name from header
        ws2.Cells(FreeRow, 7).Value = ws.Cells(i, col).Value 'transfer values
        ws2.Cells(FreeRow, 8).Value = ws.Cells(i, col + 1).Value
        ws2.Cells(FreeRow, 9).Value = ws.Cells(i, col + 2).Value
        ws2.Cells(FreeRow, 10).Value = ws.Cells(i, col + 3).Value
    Next col
Next i

'return to normal Excel status after macro has finished
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: It works well for small data ie 500 rows. I have about 17K rows & after running for more than 20 mins, it's still not complete. Possible to improve it?

Comment: @Bob, I've updated my answer to attempt to make the code run faster, please give this a try,... Also could you mark my response as an answer, if it has helped? Thanks.

Comment: It works & the processing speed is so much better!!! 17K rows in less than 5min!!! Well done.